# Regex pattern explanation

Tags: regex, perl

I am fairly new to regexes and I stubled upon a regex in perl script recently which I couldn't figure out:

```
$groups= qr/\(([^()]+|(??{$groups}))*\)/;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well if you expand it :

```
$groups= qr/
  \(                 # match an open paren (
    (                # followed by
      [^()]+         # one or more non-paren character
    |                # OR
      (??{$groups})  # the regex itself
    )*               # repeated zero or more times
  \)                 # followed by a close paren )
/x;
```

You get an elegant recursive approach to find balanced parentheses :)

Comment: Ah! That makes sense. What is the /x in the end I have never seen that.

Comment: @Kalamari That's the free space flag. It allowed me to write the regex in a more readable way and add the explanation in it.

Comment: @Kalamari, The ```/x``` lets you space it out like that, and include comments.  It basically means "Ignore white space... and comments."

Answer (score 2):

The [YAPE::Regex::Explain](https://www.metacpan.org/module/YAPE%3a%3aRegex%3a%3aExplain) module can tell you what a regex is doing:

```
% perl5.14.2 -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -E 'say YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(shift)->explain' '\(([^()]+|(??{$groups}))*\)'
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\(([^()]+|(??{$groups}))*\))

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1 (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^()]+                   any character except: '(', ')' (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (??{$groups})            run this block of Perl code (that isn't
                             interpolated until RIGHT NOW)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of \1 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

You can turn that one-liner into an alias in your profile:

```
alias re="perl -MYAPE::Regex::Explain -E 'say YAPE::Regex::Explain->new(shift)->explain'"
```

After that, you don't have to remember all that:

```
re '\(([^()]+|(??{$groups}))*\)'
```